# Git repositories for separate products, where one might want the ongoing changes of the original

Tags: git, version-control

Here is my issue -

We are working on a project, and that project is essentially a REST api, with a set of DTOs, DAOs, and Resources which will be used to make the product work.

However, we want to keep the REST api, with auth, jwt parsing, etc all in a repo which we can copy for this product, and future products - we will also open source the said stripped down REST api for other developers that just want to see something work quickly.

Now, our problem here, is that if we build the REST api, then fork it for the main project, anything that we want to change in the base REST api, will not necessarily come into the product one...

How would we do it so that we can easily take changes from the base REST api repo without messing around a whole bunch?

Basically, what we want, is to have the product API have a pom, which would point to DTO, DAO etc, and then be able to track changes from the base Rest api that we build as a separate, community driven entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate repo as either a submodule or a subtree.  Google around on those methods.  Both are not completely clean, but should do what you want.  Another option is using packages.  See below for more info

Another alternative might be to just create the base API within your repo for now, until it gets stable, and then convert it to one of the other methods.  If you do this, the package option is probably much more doable.  You can build the base API as a separate project/DLL/etc. so it stays separate from the rest of the code and will make it easy to break out in the future.

---

## Submodules

Submodules are a way of basically creating a folder in your repo that references another separate repo.  So you can open-source a repo for just the base API, and have it as a sub-module in your main repo.  This does get a little messy if you need to make updates in the sub-module itself - there are some things everyone on the team will need to follow to keep it clean (a little googling will present these issues).

## Subtrees

I haven't really dealt with subtrees, just read a little about them, but similar idea, just managing it it differently from submodules (no direct Git support for this method, if I understand correctly, but there are some advantages).

## Packages

Another option, if you will have solid versioned releases on the base API, would be to create packages from it, using NuGet, etc. and install it like any other package in your Main repo.